# How to show that a function is continuous in the topology of weak convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, self-learning, alternative-proof

Let $\Omega$ be compact, and let $\omega^* \in \Omega$ be arbitrary. Let $\Delta (\Omega)$ denote the set of all probability measures over $\Omega$, and endow $\Delta ( \Omega)$ with the topology of weak converge, i.e. $ \int g d\nu_n \to \int g d\nu$, for every continuous linear functional $g$ on $\Omega$.

Let $\mu \in \Delta ( \Omega)$, and define a function

$$ f : \Delta ( \Omega ) \to \Delta ( \Omega \times \Delta (\Omega)), $$

such that $f ( \mu ) := \mu \otimes [\delta_{\omega^*}]$.

This function is continuous (that's what I found in a book, along with the terrible question "why" in between braces!), but I am not sure about why it is continuous.

I have two guesses in order to prove the result.

1. We show that $f$ is Borel measurable, hence continuous. In order to prove that $f$ is Borel measurable, we assume that the domain and the codomain are both endowed with their correspoding Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Hence, we let $B$ be an arbitrary element of the product Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Delta ( \Omega \times \Delta (\Omega))$, and we conclude that $f^{-1} (B)$ is of course an element of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Delta ( \Omega)$ (here, $f^{-1}$ should work intuitively as a projection).
2. We prove that for an arbitrary sequence $\mu_n \in \Delta (\Omega)$, if $\mu_n \to \mu$ in $\Delta (\Omega)$, then $f(\mu_n) \to f(\mu)$ in $\Delta ( \Omega \times \Delta (\Omega))$. This should work because the definition of topology of weak convergence ensure us that $\mu_n \to \mu$ in $\Delta (\Omega)$. Hence, $f(\mu_n) \to f(\mu)$ in $\Delta ( \Omega \times \Delta (\Omega))$, because $\mu_n$ converges for the previous reason, and $[\delta_{\omega^*}]$ is constant.

**Questions:**
*Are my line of reasoning corrects in both cases?

Is actually possible to come up with an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof?*

Any feedback is most welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Some notational clarification would be helpful here (for instance it is not clear what $\Delta$ means, at least not to me).

Comment: @Ian: I edited the text.

Comment: Proving that $f$ is Borel measurable will not be enough, you need to really show it is continuous. That is, you need to show that if $\mu_n \to \mu$ (weakly) then $f(\mu_n) \to f(\mu)$ (weakly). To do that you should identify what it would mean for $f(\mu_n)$ to converge, which means you need to think about functionals on $\Omega \times \Delta(\Omega)$. The idea that $\delta_{\omega^*}$ is constant seems to be the trick, but I think you could furnish a bit more detail, expanding on what the tensor product means and so forth.

Comment: @Ian: First of all, thanks a lot for the (very useful!) comment; I was scared to death not to get any feedback, because it looks to me this is a very basic problem I am usually not able to deal with. Said so, I am happy that apparently I got the proper intuition (i.e. in the product measure, $\mu_n$ weakly converges and $\delta_{\omega^*}$ is constant). Now, may I ask two other quick things: **(1)** why proving that $f$ is Borel measurable is not enough? **(2)** Do you think it is possible to actually prove it with some $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argumentation?